# ssh connection refused from mac os x on connecting to a remote computer

Tags: ssh

I am running on Mac OS X 10.7.4.
I am unable to `ssh` to a remote computer, but when I do `ssh user@localhost`, it works fine.

The error displayed is

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to web.iiit.ac.in [14.139.82.8] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 14.139.82.8 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host web.iiit.ac.in port 22: Connection refused
```

I have enabled the root login in System Preferences and disabled firewall.

Also, `ps aux | grep ssh shows ssh-agent`, contains `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -l` and `grep ssh` in the output.

On doing `sudo launchctl list|grep ssh` it shows:

- 0   com.openssh.sshd

After this, sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd ; sudo launchctl list|grep ssh gives 
45973   -   com.openssh.sshd

Again, after checking sudo launchctl list|grep ssh after sometime, it again shows :
-   0   com.openssh.sshd

Comment: Your question and title are unclear - you're trying to connect *from* `OS X` *to* a **remote** host, and the **remote** host isn't letting you? The title implies you're connecting to the `OS X` machine, but the question is worded as if the `OS X` machine is the `localhost`. If you can clarify in the title and/or question, more help can be provided.

Comment: Sorry, I was connecting to a remote host from os x.
Edited the title now. Thanks

Comment: Are you using an ISP which proxies or otherwise interferes with outbound connections? Some ISPs block outbound connections which don't pass through their proxy servers, especially if they are mobile broadband connections.

Comment: Ya, I am using an idea mobile internet. How can I check/fix this?

Comment: Probably the best Mac tool for verifying this condition is [Layer Four Traceroute](http://pwhois.org/lft/). Run it with: `lft -d 22 -z web.iiit.ac.in`. If your ISP is blocking these connections, then the output should stop within the first few hops and never reach the university network.

Comment: Yes, the ISP is blocking these connections. I could establish the connection using another internet connection.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: having problems remote connecting SSH to Linux server... on my Mini Ventura Terminal v2.13... `su -` is not accepting root password (error message "su Authentication failure")... but on my Macbook Catalina - Terminal v2.10... still works exactly as expected... replicating behavior from years and years and years... hard to imagine such problems in 2024

Answer (score 55):

In system preferences -> sharing->enable remote login. It will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Wireless connections has well know problems with the SSH strict package receiving algorithm. I have the same problem with a WiMax connection. It would turn good if you can *establish a VPN or any kind of tunnel* to the server.

see also

[this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ptp-general/q0pwvCoVNjc)

Comment: This has made my day.

Answer (score 3):

Your remote host probably doesn't have an SSH server running (or, if it does, it's not listening on port 22).

Your tests (`ps aux`, `launchctl` etc) won't help - the issue is on the *remote* host, not the local (you've got an SSH client, because you can connect to `localhost`, but the remote host `14.139.82.8` isn't allowing connections on port 22).

Comment: I can connect to the remote host using ubuntu.
It is a college server actually, so there is no problem with that.

Comment: My University doesn't allow inbound SSH connections from outside the Uni networks. Could that be a factor in your case?

Comment: If I can connect to it using a different computer, then this might not be the problem.

Comment: I can connect to it from here in the U.S., so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran in to this problem, I found that OpenSSH was not completely installed. Install it by typing into Terminal: `sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server`

Also, check your firewall. The default SSH port is 22. Open that port.

Comment: `apt-get` is not available on Mac OS X.

Comment: To be fair, it's not specified in the question whether the remote host is running Linux, Mac OS or something else.  This answer could in theory be correct.

Comment: This solved the problem for me when trying to ssh from macOS to Ubuntu. Yes, I ran `apt-get` on Ubuntu (duh!).

Answer (score 0):

clean `known_hosts` file and try again. Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, firewall was blocking thereqest for disable the firewall i used below command in terminal and restart my pc. now everything is working fine

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 0
```

To enable firewall you can use below command

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 1
```

Thanks :)